# Txindex=1: how to recognise the blockchain with this option?

Tags: bitcoind, synchronization, reindex, txindex

This might be a dumb question: I started the Bitcoin daemon for an initial blockchain download. It immediately started downloading, I edited the Bitcoin.conf file with txindex=1. Stopped and restarted the daemon. How can I be sure the blockchain has txindex=1 correctly set? Should I reminded with the command line Bitcoind -reindex

How can I understand “looking” at a blockchain (day I downloaded from a torrent) that has txindex=1? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check the debug logs (might require `-debug` flag) and see if it is indexing transactions:

```
$ tail -f ~/.bitcoin/debug.log
```

You can also try to get a transaction by txid, and if it returns transaction data, then the blockchain has been indexed for transactions (might have to wait for sync to complete):

```
$ bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction {txid}
```

Comment: Will this ensure that the txindex contains all transactions, even those from blocks that were downloaded before -txindex was enabled?

Comment: @NateEldredge You can test it by fetching the transaction from block 1: `bitcoin-cli -datadir=. getrawtransaction $(bitcoin-cli -datadir=. getblock 00000000839a8e6886ab5951d76f411475428afc90947ee320161bbf18eb6048 | jq -r '.tx[0]')`